# What does "disappearances" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

> FUDGE (ON RADIO): Security has been and will remain the Ministry's top
> priority. Furthermore, we have convincing evidence...that these
> **disappearances** are the work... of notorious mass murderer Sirius
> Black.

What does "disappearances" refer to in the *Order of the Phoenix* film?

Comment: *"Fudge is blocking the truth at every turn and these disappearances are just how it started before."* Presumably people joining the Death Eaters (or being killed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disappearances refer to secret murders committed by the Death Eaters. It's hard to say what author J. K. Rowling had in mind, but she may have been inspired by the "disappeared ones" in Argentina's [Dirty War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_War), when the government murdered thousands of Argentines without owning up to the crime, but simply making them "disappear." The Dirty War lasted from 1974 to 1983 and was well publicized in world media; Rowling would have been about 18 in 1983 and so was probably aware of it. The book, *The Order of the Phoenix*, was not published until 2003 and the film of the same name was distributed in 2007.